# For mobile how disable autofocus on input programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, dropdown

How to avoid the autofocus kyeboard popup on mobile? and only use them if you "touch" them.

```
(function($) {
/*keep search input, but avoid autofocus on mobile*/

$('select').on('.fs-dropdown', function (e) {
    $('.fs-search input').prop('focus',false);
});
        
})(jQuery);
```

doesn't seem to work

[My Codepen](https://codepen.io/newneo/pen/GRjXPMb)

[image]

Comment: when i open codepen with android phone the keyboard popup only appears when "touching" the select

Comment: @johnSmith are you sure ?? what is your android version and the brand of your phone? I put a gif to show you what I have

Comment: Yes I am sure, I have Android 10 with security patch from first december 2020 on a moto g7 power (XT1955-4)

Comment: Oh? does this mean that in android 10 they have already muted autofocus on input? or it must be a custom code on moto g7? I have android 7 and Galaxy S6 test device. it's still strange, let's wait to see other testers on other devices

Comment: if this **mysterious code** which deactivates autofocus exists in android and applied by default it interests me, I have to find where it is hidden
and apply it for old android version? we are still not sure. you have to test on other devices

Answer (score 1):

In your **Javascript** replace **line:442** with this if you want to detect mobile with screen width(you can edit width according to you):

```
 if(screen.width > 720) {
  $wrap.find(".fs-search input").focus();
}
```

and if you want to detect mobile by browser:

```
 if(!/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
  $wrap.find(".fs-search input").focus();
}
```

To prevent losing code from update, make a js file and include it after all js files just before `</body>` with this code :

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
  var $el = $(e.target);
  var $wrap = $el.closest(".fs-wrap");
  //alert($el.attr("class"));
  var $class = $el.attr("class");
  if ($class == "fs-label") {
    setIndexes($wrap);
  }
});

function setIndexes($wrap) {
  $wrap.find(".fs-option.hl").removeClass("hl");
  if (screen.width > 720) {
    $wrap.find(".fs-search input").focus();
  } else {
    $wrap.find(".fs-search input").blur();
  }
  window.fSelect.idx = -1;
}
```

Comment: thanks @claymore  is there a way to overwrite and change it without touching the code with a function (disable wrap find focus)? if I modify the code directly I risk losing my modification with each update

Comment: @neosan Updated ! Please check

Comment: oops it does not work I tested for an hour, there is really a combination to do, look how I succeeded [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864547/acf-select2-stop-popping-out-the-keyboard-on-select) in the past, I will have to redo the same procedure, maybe a **CSS brute force solution?**

Comment: I checked it in my side, it is working. may be for you class is different ? may be you can try removing the if statement but it will disable focus on all devices.

Comment: I'll try again, I'll keep you informed, but haven't you noticed that too much code was used for such a simple task? What is his problem with this fselect ? would it be ultra sophisticated dropdown not like his brothers and sisters the dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
<select class="facetwp-dropdown hidden ready" onfocus="return false;"> // Use onfocus
  <option value="">Any Type</option>
  <option value="residential" class="d0">Residential</option>
  <option value="apartment" class="d1">Apartment</option>
  ...
</select>
```

Comment: do you have a simple and global JavaScript method?

Answer (score 0):

in your javascript on line 442 i commented out the "automatic" focus,

```
  function setIndexes($wrap) {
    $wrap.find(".fs-option.hl").removeClass("hl");
    //$wrap.find(".fs-search input").focus();
    window.fSelect.idx = -1;
  }
```

**seems to work great**

Comment: thanks you @johnsmith can you disable it otherwise with a function like i tried to do? this [fselect](https://github.com/mgibbs189/fSelect) included in a plugin is updated by its author sometimes and it might cancel my //comment if I comment on it.  now that we know the line responsible for this it must be simple? thank you again for the effort and your patience

Comment: unfortunatly this would be not easy, at least I dont see a solution, you could contact the developers to make this configurable behavior. Either just dont update or reapply the change after update.

Comment: thanks again john , I have already contacted the dev and he has ignored the subject for months .. I do not expect a miracle. I may surprise you, but in the past I managed to do this task [stop focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64864547/acf-select2-stop-popping-out-the-keyboard-on-select) with [select2](https://github.com/select2/select2) from [advanced custom field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/taxonomy/) after a long search, but obviously it does not work on this dropdown which is I think a fork of **select2**